# Is there a function to url encode dot ('.') in ruby

Tags: ruby, url

I need to send an email as a parameter in the query string.

Non of the standard functions i have tried is able to encode the '.' (dot).

```
CGI.escape('my.fake@email.com')
 => "my.fake%40email.com" 

URI.escape('my.fake@email.com')
 => "my.fake@email.com" 

URI.encode('my.fake@email.com')
 => "my.fake@email.com" 

ERB::Util.url_encode('my.fake@email.com')
 => "my.fake%40email.com"
```

I can easily do a function myself, but i just wanted to know if is there already any method.

Comment: Main question is why on the Earth do you need to encode the dot?

Comment: in rails routes the dot is a valid separator.

Comment: If those methods aren't encoding the period, then I think it's safe to assume it's not supposed to be encoded... and perhaps you can fix your problem w/the routes some other way. Maybe add an example of the problematic route to your question?

Comment: im able to solve it in many different ways actually i alredy did, it is only i wanted to understand the reason

Comment: “in rails routes the dot is a valid separator”—not in the query string.

Comment: If a dot in a URL is causing routing problems then you have a problem with your route constraints, not a URL encoding problem. And if that's the case then a little bit of [googling](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=rails+routes+dot+in+id&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Onq8V_LgIsne8Af4x5ngDQ) will point out lots of solutions.

Comment: If it's a route like `/send/:email` then you'll have problems, but `send?email=xxx` will not have the same issues. Not everything is best expressed as a URI path component.

Comment: @tadman thanks. i agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to encode the dot. After the `?` in the url, `/` and `.` don't have any specific meaning.

Answer (score 5):

As tadman pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106228/is-there-a-function-to-url-encode-dot-in-ruby#comment65561931_39106228), you will have a problem with dots if the route is something like `get "users/:email"`. Because rails considers dots as separators. As pointed in [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.2/routing.html#dynamic-segments), you will then need to add a constraint like:

```
get "users/:email", to: "users#show", constraints: { email: /.*/ }
```

And with that you don't need to escape dots in the url.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape characters that wouldn't normally be escaped by providing a regex as the 2nd argument to `URI.escape`

```
URI.escape('a@b.c', /\./)
 => "a@b%2Ec"
```

(keep in mind that providing your own regex overrides the default, so now nothing but `.` will be encoded)